# How to create comma separated values from a string in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to coding and I am trying to convert a text file into a csv file. So far my code produces this

```
['CP003057.2\tPlus\t2.713014377\t1884078\t1884060\t\t\t\t\n'], 

['CP003057.2\tPlus\t2.752912689\t1084194\t1084176\t\t\t\t\n'], 

['CP003057.2\tPlus\t2.756875754\t2915112\t2915094\t\t\t\t\n'], 

['CP003057.2\tPlus\t2.758370469\t547344\t547326\t\t\t\t\n'],
```

I need to replace the "\t" with a "," so that I have multiple strings within each list separated by commas. Here is the code that I have so far

```
text = 'file.txt'

data = []

with open(text) as f:

        for line in f:
             data.append([word for word in line.split(" ") if word])

print(data)
```

Comment: I'm no python guy, but your indentation seems off.

Comment: The indentation is "off", but it'll run just fine. That's not the issue here

Comment: Try replacing the `line.split(" ")` with `line.split()`. It splits on any whitespace by default.

Comment: Take a look at what this does: `'CP003057.2\tPlus\t2.758370469\t547344\t547326\t\t\t\t\n'.replace('\t', ',')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace '\t' with ',' you can just do

```
line.replace('\t', ',')
```

which replaces each instance of \t with a comma for each line that has been created.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [built-in python module for interacting with CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) files you may want to look at as it gives you a lot more control over reading/writing, that said, the simple fix is just to use your delimiter as the split argument...  specifically, if you are using a comma `,` to split the columns, then you would want to use:

```
line.split(', ')
```

If you are using a vertical line `|`, then you would want to use:

```
line.split('| ')
```